# I am trying to figure out how to convert columns in a string to row using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, regex, string

The code I am working on requires that I take a all the characters in a string, break it into rows then log all the columns back into a single string.

I have broken the character into rows, but I am unable to log the columns back into a new row:

```
let String= nodeStack.nodeValue;
// this wiil structure the text into a 8 columnns
let el=String.match(/.{1,8}/g);

for (i in el){
    let node = document.createTextNode(el[i]);
    let paraStack = document.createElement('p');
    paraStack.appendChild(node);
    stackCard.appendChild(paraStack);


    //this is to log all the columns into a single row
    //this is the part i am having issues with
    let res = node.nodeValue;

    let codMsg= [];
    res.split('\n').forEach(function(v){
        v.split('').forEach(function(v1, i){
            codMsg[i] = (codMsg [i]|| '') + v1;
        });
    });
    console.log(codMsg.join('\n')) ;
}
```

The current result displays something like:

```
// console.log(el) gives
hertijhp
joiunjdk
njjooool

// console.log(codMsg.join('\n')) logs everything like this
h
e
r
t
i...
// instead of "hjneojrij"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide the input for your example

Comment: You can test with any input value

Comment: Actually I can't, as `stackCard is not defined`. What I'm trying to say is that your code should be reproducible in order to have it examined by other SO users

Comment: Please check the code in your question after reading: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a string and break it into groups like you have:

```js
let s= "ThisIsAReallyLongStringWithNoSpacesInItAtAll"
let groups = s.match(/.{1,8}/g);

console.log(groups)
```

As you can see each row has at most 8 characters, so in the end you will want an array of length 8. For each of those 8 arrays at a particular index you want all the `string[index]` values from your groups. This can be expressed as a map:

```
groups.map(s => s[i]).join(''))
```

That takes each string from your groups, gets element `i` and joins it back to a string. You can do this for each index `0` - `8` using `Array.from` (or a `for` loop and `push()`) and end up with something like:

```js
let s= "ThisIsAReallyLongStringWithNoSpacesInItAtAll"
let groups = s.match(/.{1,8}/g);

let a = Array.from({length: 8}, (_,i)  => groups.map(s => s[i]).join(''))
console.log(a)
```

`join()` will ignore the `undefined` values we get when we try to index past the length of the shorter columns giving us shorter strings for the last columns like `"RnWaA"`